# Pipe Named Fifo

Tags: pipe, c, c++, fifo

I am implementing a named pipe to write and read data between two processes in cpp. The first process acquires a feature point from an image in real time while the second reads this feature point. It works fine but after a couple of data exchanges between the two processes, the talker code freezes. I know I need to close a pipe in order to be able to read from it and when I tried to close the file descriptor in the talker code outside a while loop, the listener file could not access new values of the variable. I can't find a way around it at the moment. What could I possibly be missing?

Here's a MCVE of a function that writes a variable to a fifo file:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

/*Function Prototypes*/
void(cv::Mat frame);    
int(talker);

 int talker(float depthright)
 {
   int fd;
   char depthstring[1024];    
   sprintf(depthstring, "%4.4f", depthright);

   char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

   mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);           /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
   fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY/* | O_NONBLOCK*/);       
   write(fd, depthstring, sizeof(depthright) );    

   /* close FIFO and delete fifo names from file system */
   close(fd);
   unlink(myfifo); 

   return 0;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
 cv::Mat frame;
//convert frame to grayscale, equalize histogram of grayed frame
//detect faces and then detect eyes; acquire eye depth values as depthright
 talker(depthright);     //call fifo talker funtion
return 0;
 }
```

The listener is below:

```
int main()
 {    
  int fd;
  char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
  char buf[1024];

    while(1)
    {
        //READ actual depth fifo
        fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
        read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
        float depth = strtof(buf, NULL);
        printf("\ndepth actual: %4.2f", depth);              
    }    

     //Close read buffers
     close(fd);

     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: It's totally wrong to send a string buffer representing a float by `sizeof(float)` bytes.  And the listener immediately runs into a tight busy loop forever...  What do you expect the program to achieve?

Comment: I’m sorry; what does this have to do with [MarkWest Energy Partners](http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/mwe)?  Or are you talking about Modeling Workflow Engine or Multi-Word Expressions?   … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  Oh, wait; do you mean Minimum Working Example?

Comment: We prefer [Minimal, Complete, \[and\] Verifiable Examples (MCVEs)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here (see also [Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (SSCCE)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22754/195817).  Your example is neither complete nor compilable inasmuch it doesn’t show how `talker()` is invoked — specifically, how is it getting called *more than once* — so we have no way of understanding how “it works fine” for “a couple of data exchanges”, and, accordingly, no good way to understand how it “freezes”.

Comment: Please don’t post code that fails to do the bare minimum, obvious error checking.  Your `talker()` routine creates and destroys the FIFO, so obviously it doesn’t always exist.  And yet your `main()` code says `fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)` without checking for error (ENOENT), and then calls `read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF)` with a `fd` that might be `-1`.  And, even if you got the FIFO open, since it’s open in non-blocking mode, `read` can return `0` to indicate that no data are available (or it can return a partial message).

Comment: How do you use ENOENT for error checking?

Comment: @Calorified, you check the return value of each system call. Read the man page (`man 2 read` for the `read` function, for example. Syscalls are in section 2 of the manual, while library calls are in section 3) to see which return value means an error for each system or library call. Usually, 0 = success, -1 = error. If the return value indicates an error, you can check the variable `errno` (defined in `<errno.h>`) to see why there's an error. If a file failed to open because it didn't exist, `errno` will equal `ENOENT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only sending `sizeof(float)` bytes, which is only a substring of `depthstring`, whose actual size is `strlen(depthstring)+1`, not `sizeof(float)`.

One thing you could do is eliminate the conversion to and from a string. Since both processes reading a named FIFO are on the same machine (no, FIFOs don't work over NFS), you can assume that a `float` is represented the same way in both processes. Therefore:

```
int talker(float depthright)
 {
   int fd;
   const char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

   mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);           /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
   fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY/* | O_NONBLOCK*/);
   write(fd, &depthright, sizeof(depthright) );    

   /* close FIFO and delete fifo names from file system */
   close(fd);
   /* Don't delete the FIFO yet. The reader may not have opened
    * it yet.
    */

   return 0;
}
```

And then:

```
int main()
 {    
  int fd;
  const char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

    while(1)
    {
        //READ actual depth fifo
        fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
        float depth;
        read(fd, &depth, sizeof(depth));
        // Close read buffers now, since we open it with
        // each iteration. Waiting until after the loop
        // will result in only the last fd being closed.

        // Furthermore, there's a tight limit on how many
        // FDs you can have open at once.
        close(fd);    
        printf("\ndepth actual: %4.2f", depth);
        // Without this, libc may hold the output in a buffer
        // until the next float is read.
        fflush(stdout);
    }    
     /* NOT REACHED. The compiler may actually delete this code, since
      *  it can prove that this part will never be executed.
      */ 
     unlink(myfifo); 
     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Actually, since `fd` is opened in `O_NONBLOCK` mode, `read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF)` will ***never*** block.  Even if it weren’t in `O_NONBLOCK` mode, it wouldn’t block until it receives `MAX_BUF` bytes; it would only block until it received ***one*** byte.

Comment: _Furthermore, there's a tight limit on how many_. What is this limit, please?

Comment: @G-Man, whoops, I didn't notice that he didn't have `O_NONBLOCK` commented out there.

Comment: @Calorified, the limit is defined somewhere in `/proc/sys/`, I can't remember where exactly. It can vary from system to system, and you can change it if you're root. There also seems to be a per-process setting you can modify with `setrlimit` (or `ulimit -n` from bash).

Answer (score 0):

A small part of your problem may lie in the fact
that you are doing an `open` inside your `while (1) … read` loop
(without closing the resulting file descriptor in the loop). 
Your code can be expected to accumulate
hundreds of file descriptors for the FIFO. 
Typically, after you hit a thousand,
the `open` will start failing because of too many open files (EMFILE).